# trying to create an array of classes(well default objects)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I have a class called `Game` and inside of game I want a `board` variable of the type `Tool` which I already made, I implemented the Tool class and had inserted default values in, when I try to create the array in the private section of `Game`  I get a few errors;

> syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
>
> missing type specificier - int assumed.
>
> unexpected token(s) precending ';'

My code so far:

```
class Game {
private:
Tool board[64]; <-- errors here
}
    class Tool {
      public:
          Tool(int n = -1, int x =-1 , int y = -1, bool side = false) {
             ......
          }
    }
```

Comment: Put `class Tool` before `class Game`.

Comment: Swap the class definitions: an array needs its element type to be fully defined before use.

Comment: No, that's not your code so far. It's missing `;` and is not even close to describing the whole issue. Create a [mcve].

Comment: I have the ; at the end of the classes already, and have swapped their places, still getting the errors though

Comment: It may sound ridiculous, but.. have you saved the source file before re-compiling?

Comment: oh just forgot to rebuild it.

Comment: Applying the suggestions/answers and writing a code someone would reasonably try compiling, gives this https://ideone.com/QVTAnp which compiles fine. If you still have errors, you'll have to provide us with a mcve (cf StoryTeller comment) which exhibits them

Comment: do yourself a favor and be careful with "classes" vs "objects". You have an array of objects not an array of classes

Answer (score 0):

You need semicolons on the end of each class declaration.
Tool needs to be declared before it is used (i.e. above Game)

Comment: forgot to rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of bugs in your code. class syntax looks like

```
class class_name {
    private: 
       data-member;
    public:
       member-function
};<-- you are missing this, should be closed using ;
```

Next thing, class `Tool` should be defined before class `Game` or do the **forward declaration** of class `Tool` first.

```
   class Tool {
      public:
          Tool(int n = -1, int x =-1 , int y = -1, bool side = false) {
             ......
          }
    };
    class Game {
       private:
       Tool board[64]; 
    };
```

Comment: already had the semicolons, nontheless still getting the errors

Comment: forgot to rebuild it my bad